# Using MTM test recorder as a base for a load test

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I'm not sure if this is what I can do with MTM but I am asking.... If we use MTM Action recorder to record the steps of a thick gui client (not a web test). When we save it, I know we can open it in Visual Studio. If we try can convert that to a load test will just convert the underlying calls to code and not really use the UI so that we can generate Load?

Comment: You've recorded UI transactions and you want it to do something else. I'm not sure how that would work. What have you tried so far?